# Is there a Matlab equivalent to Pythons @classmethod?

Tags: matlab, static-methods

In Matlab, I want to create an alternative constructor using a static method, and I want this constructor to be able to inherit to subclasses. I fail to do so, because I cannot get a reference to the *calling* class inside a static method.

Consider this example code with superclass A that has an alternative constructor `fromSomething`:

```matlab
classdef A

    properties
        a
    end
    
    methods
        function obj = A(a)
            if nargin
                obj.a = a;
            end
        end
    end

    methods(Static)

        function obj = fromSomething()
            obj = A(42);
        end
    end
end
```

An instance of `A` can be created by calling `A.fromSomething()`.

Now consider subclass B:

```matlab
classdef B < A

    methods
        function someFunctionality(obj)
        end
    end

end
```

Calling `B.fromSomething()` gives an object of type `A`. That is not the desired behavior. How can this code be changed such that `B.fromSomething()` gives me an object of type `B` with minimal code re-use?

In Python, this would be done using a `@classmethod` decorator.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
    a : float

    @classmethod
    def from_something(cls):
        return cls(42)
    

class B(A):

    def some_functionality(self):
        ...
```

Note that in the Python code `B.from_something()` will return an object of type `B`.

I've tried to obtain the class name of the current class using `dbstack`:

```matlab
...
        function obj = fromSomething()
            cls = currentClass();
            obj = feval(cls.Name, 42);
        end
...
```

```matlab
function    [ cls, str ] = currentClass( )
% Taken from https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/77387-any-way-to-get-the-current-class
dbk = dbstack( 1, '-completenames' );
if isempty( dbk )
    str = 'base';
else
    str = dbk(1).name;
end
cac = regexp( str, '\.', 'split' );
switch  numel( cac )
    case 1
    case 2
        cls = meta.class.fromName( cac{1} );
        str = cac{2};
    case 3
    otherwise
end
end
```

However, dbstack returns the class that the function is *defined* on (in this case: `A`), rather than the class the function is *called* on (in this case, `B` when calling `B.fromSomething()`). As a result `B.fromSomething()` will still return an object of type `A`.

Comment: In MATLAB it is much easier to have the constructor take different sets of input arguments than in Python. For example you can easily “overload” based on the type of the second input. Then you’d do `B()` or `B(1)` or `B(something)`, and the function would do different things.

Comment: @Cris Luengo Thanks, that might indeed be a way forward. Still, I love the explicitness of alternative constructors over a single constructor with multiple signatures that are not explicitly written out. Especially in combination with the rather newly introduced argument blocks having multiple functions instead of a single constructor would be great.

Comment: I don't think you should try to make a language do stuff in the way another language does it. That just ends up in headache. If you program in MATLAB, use MATLAB style and conventions.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that reading from the docs, MATLAB does not seem to have class methods:

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/how-to-use-methods.html

In fact this is not a common type of method in most programming languages.

Comment: Thanks. I realize that, if possible at all, this will involve a 'homebrew' solution.

Comment: @lvdgraaff yeah, just was answering the explicit question in the title. I am not sure you can.....

Answer (score 2):

`@staticmethod` is a very Pythony thing, and you need it because Python doesn't do function overloading, and doesn't make it easy to simulate it. In MATLAB it is quite common for a function to have multiple signatures, and do different things depending on which inputs are given.

Your use case, I presume, is to construct an object given a specific input `something`: `A.fromSomething(something)`, as opposed to a plain `A()`, or a `A.fromFoo(foo)`.

In MATLAB all these cases are typically handled by the same constructor. You can make it look like this:

```matlab
classdef A
   % ...
   methods
      function obj = A(arg)
         if nargin == 0
            % case A()
         else
            if isa(arg, 'Something')
               % case A(something)
            elseif isa(arg, 'Foo')
               % case A(foo)
            else
               error('Illegal input')
            end
         end
      end
   end
end
```